# Getting Sum by looping a list within a list c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
public class GRNMaster
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string GRNNo { get; set; }
    public List<GRNDetails> GRNDetails { get; set; }
}

public class GRNDetails
{
    public string GRNID { get; set; }
    public string ItemID { get; set; }
    public string ItemType { get; set; }
    public int RecevedQty { get; set; }
}
```

above classes contains some of the properties of GRN header class and Detail class. i Grn can consist of many items so that "List GRNDetails" is there to keep them.

I take a GRN List from a method which will store in the variable GrnList

```
public List<GRNMaster> GrnList
```

I have a list of Items IDs

```
public List<string> ItemIDList
```

In the controller I want to loop the ItemIDList (List ItemIDList) and get sum for that particular item based on the List

```
int ItemQty = 0;

foreach (var item in ItemIDList)
{
   ItemQty = 0;

   var ItemQty =  //some code using GrnList

    // rest of the programming code based on the 
    //  item qty
}
```

Comment: you have list of ids based on that u want to retrieve some of the data ?

Comment: You can linq sum done even have to write this kind of elaborated for loop

Comment: Do you want to sum all ReceivedQty?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using LINQ

```
var totalQty = 0;
foreach (var item in ItemIDList)
{
    var sumOfCurrentItem = GrnList.SelectMany(s => s.GRNDetails
                           .Where(f => f.ItemID == item)).Select(f => f.RecevedQty).Sum();

    totalQty += sumOfCurrentItem ;
}
```

Or even a one liner replacement of the  `foreach` loop (*Credit goes to ReSharper :)* )

```
int totalQty = ItemIDList.Sum(item => GrnList
                  .SelectMany(s => s.GRNDetails.Where(f => f.ItemID == item))
                  .Select(f => f.RecevedQty).Sum());
```

Comment: Thank you Shyji for you answer.
no need of the last line of you first answer ( totalQty += sumOfCurrentItem ;)...
I tried the first answer you posted

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your requirements correctly then this is what you need:

```
IEnumerable<int> query =
    from grn in GrnList
    from grnDetail in grn.GRNDetails
    join itemID in ItemIDList on grnDetail.ItemID equals itemID
    select grnDetail.RecevedQty;

int ItemQty = query.Sum();
```